# Highchart Legend's Border

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

When using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com), I render the series dynamically using AJAX + PHP.

The arrangements work nicely, but the only drawback is the legend's border as shown below...

[image: Legend's Border Problem]

Is there any method to do border resize ? Or any other mean to resolve the problem ?

Comment: Can you give some example code to reproduce the problem?  I tried here: http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/gdAwP/ but the legend seems to behave.

Comment: Hi Mark, very sorry for late reply. Hm... I'll try to upload the source here. Will get back to you soon.

Comment: its better to remove the border like  http://jsfiddle.net/zE5wS/7/

Comment: Hi Sreenath, this can solve my problem. how can I mark this as an answer :p

Comment: hi Dino glad that it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question actually has been done by Sreenath Plakkat in the comment, that is removing border.